# Freeze a variable added to an eventlistener function

Tags: javascript, html

I have several elements that get eventlisteners added so I can capture event data. It works great but I need each to have a unique ID. If you look at the snippet below, you can see that the ID will always last value.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var id = i + 1;
  
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    buttonClicked(id);
  }
}

function buttonClicked(id) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Button ID: ' + id;
}
```

```html
<button class="class">Button 1</button>
<button class="class">Button 2</button>

<hr>

<div id="output"></div>
```

I am aware that you could put the onclick event in the HTML, but I need the event data. It also needs to have the onclick in as a `function()` as I have it. Is there a  way I could somehow freeze the `id` variable value for the function?

Comment: `var` does not use block scope. `const` would be best since the value doesn't change, but `let` would also work.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, thanks! Never would have been able to find that. Seemed like this question would have been answered before. Can't delete it now since there is an answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the closure around the looping variable `i` and the `id` variable. Change the variable declarationd to `let i = 0` and `let id = i + 1` to create a unique scope for them upon each loop iteration.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  let id = i + 1;
  
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    buttonClicked(id);
  }
}

function buttonClicked(id) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Button ID: ' + id;
}
```

```html
<button class="class">Button 1</button>
<button class="class">Button 2</button>

<hr>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Technically you can get away with only changing `id` to `let` or `const`. `i` can still be `var`